# How to get only the first 6 months action of all my records

Tags: tableau-api

I'm pretty new in Tableau. I have looked at the forum already and the answered suggested. But I'm not quite sure it match my question.

I have a bunch of records. This is about registration for a sport lesson depending on time. All of them have a start date and and some of them a finish date. The other never finish (They continue until date T with T = now).
My goal is to compare only the first 6 months of all my records, I think there are 50 of them, like the evolution during this period of time. So, for some the start date would be in January 2009, for some other, it would be in May 2016, etc.

As field provided, I have the start date and the number of person that have subscribed those lesson through time.

So, do you if there is any to achieve this goal? Is there enough detail for you to understand what I am saying ?

Thx to you guys !!

EDIT 
You can find enclosed a screenshot of the result that I already have.

[number of registration for all lesson through time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHzCw.png)

I'm not sure to be clear, what I try to do is to compare the first 6 months only of each courses. So the evolution of the first 6 months of this course compare to the evolution of the first 6 months of this other course and so on :)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and a rough outline of how you want it to look? And if you have done anything in Tableau, can you provide a screenshot so we can see your shelves?

Comment: Have  at my below solution and see how you go @Joff

Comment: @SamM, I have done it

Comment: @Joff my same logic works as before just with an edit to the calculation. I have updated my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are wanting to show only the first six months of your data but you want this by each category.

I am assumuming that by definition this means 6 months from the first record in your data for each category.

In order to achieve this I would create a true/false flag using a level of detail expression. As you are new to tableau I would suggest you do some reading on this but basically you can force a calculation to be at a certain level of the data rather than at the row level. You use this to find the minimum date in the table and then use a date diff to return true if the actual date field is within 6 months of this.

Create a calculated field as follows:

```
[date] <= DATEADD('month', 6, { FIXED [category] :min([date])})
```

Then drag this onto your filters pane and select "TRUE". This should give you only the first six months of records for each category. 
Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thx for your help. However, this is not the result that I am looking for. I have updated my post with an image. Plus, thx to what you said, I can compare the first 6 month of every data contained in my tableau. I would like to compare the first 6 month of record A, the first 6 month of record B, the first 6 month of record C, and so on. That way I can see the evolution of the first 6 month for each record !

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thx :)

Comment: @Joff no problems, could you accept my answer if possible